# How to split different line into strings

Tags: java, string, split

I am trying to solve the [Panacea - truth or lie](https://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/237/) challenge.

Basically I have to check that the sum of two sets of numbers in a text file (that can contains more than one line) is equal or not. The first set is an hexadeciaml number and the second binary; the separation of the two sets is done by number 9 (I have problem using split and the parameter `|` as delimiting expression, do you know why ?)

Example of input:

> 64 6e 78 9 100101100 11110
>
> 5e 7d 59 9 1101100 10010101 1100111

If it run once the code is fine, but into the while loop I receive a `NumberFormatExceptions`.

Here is my final code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class test  {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException  {
        BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new FileReader ("C:\\Users\\Steel\\Desktop\\JAVA\\somme\\som.txt"));
   
        int somma_bin;
        int somma_hex; 
        int i;
        String ciao = "9";
        List<String> binehex = new ArrayList<>();
        String prova;
        while ((prova = buff.readLine()) != null) {
            somma_bin = 0;
            somma_hex = 0;
            binehex = Arrays.asList(prova.split(" "));
            i = 0;

            while (!(binehex.get(i)).equals(ciao)) {  
                somma_hex  += Integer.parseInt(binehex.get(i), 16);
                i++;
            }

            i++;
            while (i < (binehex.size()-1)) {
                somma_bin  += Integer.parseInt(binehex.get(i), 2);
                i++;
            }

            if (somma_bin == somma_hex) {
                System.out.println("true");
            } else {
                System.out.println("false");
            }
            System.out.println(prova);
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Which while loop does the execption get thrown in? Also, can you also tidy up the indentiation of your code?

Answer (score 1):

I can't see an obvious problem, other than there's a lot of code.

Try some more structure:

```
String line; // given a line
String[] parts = line.split(" 9 ");
int sumHex = Arrays.stream(parts[0].split(" ")).mapToInt(s -> Integer.parseInt(s, 16)).sum();
int sumBin = Arrays.stream(parts[1].split(" ")).mapToInt(s -> Integer.parseInt(s, 2)).sum();
System.out.println(sumHex == sumBin);
```

I'm not sure what relevance splitting by `"|"` has, since that's not in your posted code, but if you want to split on a pipe, you must delimit it, because the pipe char has a special meaning in regex:

```
string.split("\\|");
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, you could split a line by the |-Character, like that:

```
String[] strArr = prova.split("|");
```

Then you have two array-elements in strArr, strArr[0] contains strings that represent the hex-numbers, strArr[1] represents the binary-numbers.

Then you could split each array again:

```
String[] hexArr = strArr[0].split(" ");
String[] binArr = strArr[0].split(" ");
```

After that, you can make a sum of the values as you did in two different while-loops.
In case of hexArr, you should check if the last element is null or "" because there is a whitespace between the last number and the |-Character.

Answer (score 0):

This is solution for your code -

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Steel\\Desktop\\JAVA\\somme\\som.txt"));

        int somma_bin;
        int somma_hex;
        int i;
        String ciao = "9";

        String prova;

        while ((prova = buff.readLine()) != null) {

            somma_bin = 0;
            somma_hex = 0;
            //System.out.println(prova.split("\\|")[0]);
            //System.out.println(prova.split("\\|")[1]);
            String bin[] = null;
            String hex[] = null;
            if(prova.contains("|")){
                bin = prova.split("\\|")[1].split(" ");
                hex = prova.split("\\|")[0].split(" ");
            } else{
                continue;
            }

            for(String str : bin){
                if(str!=null && !str.isEmpty()){
                    somma_bin += Integer.valueOf(str.trim(), 2);
//                  System.out.println("bin - "+Integer.valueOf(str.trim(), 2)+"("+str+")");
                }
            }

            for(String str : hex){
                if(str!=null && !str.isEmpty()){
                    somma_hex += Integer.valueOf(str.trim(), 16);
//                  System.out.println("hex - "+Integer.valueOf(str.trim(), 16)+"("+str+")");
                }
            }

            if (somma_bin == somma_hex) {
                System.out.println("true");
            }

            else {
                System.out.println("false");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] a) throws Exception {

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("64 6e 78 | 100101100 11110");
    list.add("5e 7d 59 | 1101100 10010101 1100111");
    list.add("93 75 | 1000111 1011010 1100010");

    for (String line : list) {
        String splits[] = line.split("\\|");
        int hexTotal = Arrays.stream(splits[0].split(" ")).mapToInt(v -> {
            if (v.length() == 0)
                return 0;
            else
                return Integer.parseInt(v, 16);
        }).sum();
        int binTotal = Arrays.stream(splits[1].split(" ")).mapToInt(v -> {
            if (v.length() == 0)
                return 0;
            else
                return Integer.parseInt(v, 2);
        }).sum();
        System.out.println(hexTotal <= binTotal);
    }

}
```

ArrayList `list` can be populated from  a file.